# Books on Differential Calculus.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What book would you recommend for someone who has read "Differential calculus for beginners by Joseph Edwards"? Something that has both the in-depth explanation of the concepts and a few problems that represent practical implementations and Exercises for practice.

Comment: Did you look at [previously asked questions about calculus book recommendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation%20calculus?sort=MostFrequent)?

Comment: Yes but I was searching for a path for a student who had gone through the introductory phase can move forward.